# Too many boolean expressions in if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, lint

I have this warning in Lint: **R0916: Too many boolean expressions in if statement (6/5) (too-many-boolean-expressions)**

Thats my code:

```
if (
    old_image.get("var") == "Type1"
    or old_image.get("var") == "Type2"
    or old_image.get("var") == "Type3"
) and (
    new_image.get("var") != "Type1"
    and new_image.get("var") != "Type2"
    and new_image.get("var") != "Type3"
):
```

How do I remove this lint error?

Answer (score 9):

You can try this:

```
types = [ "Type1", "Type2", "Type3"]
if old_image.get("var") in types and new_image.get("var") not in types:
```